# ¿Cómo validar con jquery.validate un formulario dividido en varias tabs en Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Tengo un formulario donde divido los campos en diferentes *tabs*, y lo estoy validando con *jquery.validate* pero al momento de la validación al parecer sólo está tomando los *input* que se encuentran visibles, es decir los que se muestran en el *tab* activo.

Mi formulario luce de la siguiente forma:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" submit.delegate="save()">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#personal" aria-controls="personal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#ubicacion" aria-controls="ubicacion" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Ubicación</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#contacto" aria-controls="contacto" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contacto</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="personal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PrimerNombre" class="control-label col-xs-3">Primer Nombre</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input required type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentItem.PrimerNombre" name="PrimerNombre">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--- ...  -->
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="ubicacion">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Direccion" class="control-label col-xs-3">Dirección</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentItem.Direccion" name="Direccion">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--- ...  -->
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="contacto">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Celular" class="control-label col-xs-3">Celular</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input required maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentItem.Celular" name="Celular">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--- ...  -->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

La validación se dispara a la hora de enviar los datos del formulario así:

```
save() {

    if ($("form").validate().form()) {

        //Código Guardado

    }

}
```

**Nota**

Estoy usando `aurelia.io` para bindar los campos y el modelo que está en `TypeScript` pero no creo que esto afecte en algo la funcionalidad del *plugin* de validación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente no es buena idea validar campos que no estén visibles, pero puedes habilitarlo con este código:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: [],
});
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías tener alguna función que te recorra todos los elementos del formulario y verifique la validez de cada elemento por separado

```
var esValido = true;
$(formulario).find("input, select").each(function () {
    $(this).valid();        
});
```